# How to create a dynamic datarow in for loop in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to create data row in for loop with each row have unique name.

```
for(int;i=0;i<12;i++)
{

Datarow i=new Datarow();
}
```

Is it possible in asp.net.I have to create 12 datarows with unique name

Comment: Your code won't _even_ compile. Can you please show short but complete program demonstrating your problem?

Comment: I have to create 12 datarows dynamiclly with unique name

Comment: What do you mean by "unique name"? Do yo mean ID? What is the  data?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this. Hope this will works for you.

```
DataRow dr;        

 for (int i = 0; i < chkcnt; i++)
    {
        dr = local_ds2.Tables["ACHFile"].NewRow();
        dr["EmpID"] = EmpID[i];
        dr["Name"] = Empname[i];
        dr["BankRoutingNumber"] = BnkRoutingNumber[i];
        dr["BankAccount"] = BnkAccount[i];
        dr["BankAccountTypeID"] = AchDB.strBankTypeID[i];
        dr["Amount"] = AchDB.Amount1[i];
        if (AchDB.strBankTypeID[i].ToString() == "D")
            strBankAccntType = "BankAccountTypeID='" + AchDB.strBankTypeID[i].ToString() + "'";
        local_ds2.Tables["ACHFile"].Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Distinct`Keyword for creating a collection with different keys, like that:

```
List<string> ages = new List<string> { "twentyOne", "FortySix", "FortySix", "FiftyFive", "SevenTeen", "twentyOne", "FiftyFive", "FiftyFive" };
List<int> realAges = new List<int> { 21, 46, 46, 55, 17, 21, 55, 55 };  

ages = ages.Distinct();
DataTable table = some table you use
DataRow row = table.NewRow();

 for (int i = 0;i < ages.Count(); ++i)
 { 
     if (realAges.Count() < i)
     {
        row[ages[i]] = realAges[i]
     }
 }
```

Comment: Could you please put a sample code..Is not working @israel altar

Comment: Its not getting created.How to add data row in your code?@israel altar

Comment: Thank You.I wiil check that.@israel altar

Comment: I have to set value for each datarow.How to do that??DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1["Data"] = "series1";
        dr1["Value1"] = 32;
        dr1["Value2"] = 45;

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Declare a DataTable
        DataTable dtNames = new DataTable("dtNames");
        // Add column to the DataTable
        dtNames.Columns.Add("Name");

        DataRow drName = null;
        // Loop to add new rows with unique names
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            drName = dtNames.NewRow();
            drName["Name"] = "Name0" + i;

            dtNames.Rows.Add(drName);
        }
```